# Getting reference to object behind Rc

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement simple DOM structure, but getting confused with rust(or not) memory model.

Here is simple example:

```
struct NodeData {
    text: String,
}

struct Node(Rc<RefCell<NodeData>>);

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Node {
        Node(Rc::new(RefCell::new(NodeData {
            text: String::new()
        })))
    }

    fn set_text(&self, text: String) {
        self.0.borrow_mut().text = text;
    }

    // it works, but has unneeded, expensive clone
    // pub fn text(&self) -> String {
    //     self.0.borrow().text.clone()
    // }

    pub fn text(&self) -> &String {
        // ???
    }
}

fn main() {
    let node = Node::new();
    node.set_text("text".to_string());
    if node.text() == "text" {
        println!("equal");
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to get reference to *text* field, not it's copy.

I see only two alternatives:

1. Using `RcString(Rc<RefCell<String>>)` instead of raw `String`. But it will produce a lot of boilerplate code and some overhead.
2. Implementing method like `is_text_equal(&self, text: &String)`. But it's ugly.

Also, there is possibility, that I'm doing something totally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation

The problem here is that you are managing something (`NodeData`) within a `RefCell`. In order for `RefCell` to work, it can't give out references without limitations. Instead the only way to obtain a reference to the inner data is by using a scope guard. From the [`RefCell` documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```
fn borrow(&self) -> Ref<T>
```

Instead of returning `&T` like you would expect, a `Ref` is returned. This `Ref` object in turn can give you a reference via the `deref`-operator method. But the returned reference is only valid as long as the `Ref` object lives! That way the `RefCell` can keep track of all its borrows.

#### Possible solutions

You could just return the `Ref` object, the user would be able to use it nearly as a simple `&String`. However, this can easily lead to panics because the user borrows it accidentally again. Look at this:

```
let text = my_node.text();
println!("the text is {} chars long", text.len());
my_node.set_text("hi".into());   // boom!
```

The problem is that the inner value of the `RefCell` is considered borrowed immutably as long as a `Ref` object is alive. In this case `text` is a `Ref` object and thus borrows the inner value. In `set_text` you attempt to borrow the inner value mutably.

---

Of course you could also implement some utility functions yourself, as you already said (2.).

Honestly, **I would say that you should rethink your design**. Is a `RefCell` really needed? Often it's not. And usually `RefCells` are used only for private, hidden variables and never exposed to the user. The problems mentioned above are one reason for not doing it.

Of course this answer is not very satisfying, but I think there is no better solution.

#### Additional hints

- A `&String` reference is not more powerful than a `&str` reference. So usually only `&str` are used. The same goes for `&Vec<T>` (hardly used) and `&[T]`. Note that this is only valid for immutable references -- `&mut String` is a whole lot more powerful than `&mut str`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, but as I understand, I should return `Ref<NodeData>`, not `Ref<String>`, which I need. NodeData must be private. About design - I don't know. I'm trying to implement simple DOM structure without unsafe, using only existing methods/structs, and not via creating everything from scratch. And `RefCell` is only way I find to implement mutable data.

Comment: @RazrFalcon Use the `map` function to get only the text: `Ref::map(self.0.borrow(), |n| &n.text)`

Comment: @Arjan Thanks! That's exactly what I want. Only difference between my current implementation, that uses Rc, is that I need two methods: regular and _mut. As far as I understand - there is no performance cost for Ref::map, because it's just a wrapper, right?